# Automatic bookmarking of recently edited parts of a file

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I'd like to quickly see "hot" positions of the file I have been recently edited, so I can quickly jump between them without inserting manual bookmarks.

- Does Aptana offer this kind of feature?
- Are there any Eclipse plug-ins doing this?

Comment: Jump to last edit location with Ctrl+Q. But a more comprehensive support would be really nice, I agree!

Comment: Also note that I am using OSX, so it's probably CMD-Q :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse does it (I am running 3.7.1):

Window->Prefs->General->Editors->Text Editors->Quick Diff

(or just type quick diff into the preference page search)

Enable quick diff, show differences in rulers - you can change the colours to make it more visible.

Comment: Lovely! I have been using Eclipse since version 1.0 and somehow had missed this.

Comment: funnily enough I only discovered it this week

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is utilizing Mylyn. Just activate a task and a context will automatically be created that tracks changes on a method level, even highlighting important changes in bold. You can switch off the "focusing" (i.e. only showing the active and edited classes / ressources) in the project / explorer view if that annoys you. But Mylyn is a little more intensive, it only shows its full potential with a little bit of familiarisation.

Comment: Thank you, but I am working on Javascript, not Java. Mylyn would be also an overkill.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Yes, Mylyn is quite hefty and should only be used if more of its features are incorporated into the workflow. I agree, for the given task alone (especially for JS) it is too much. (Oh, but it retains its state after saving, in contrast to the Quick Diff.)